# Foreign key on source struct?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm starting with Gorm and trying to model the following:

```
type MyLink struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title             string
    Url               string
}

// group of links under a single title
type MyLinkSection struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title string
    Links []MyLink
}

type MyPage struct {
    gorm.Model
    PageUrl     MyLink
    Artists     []MyLinkSection
}
```

As you can see I want to be able to refer to the same struct, `MyLink` as both a foreign keyed object from `MyPage` but also as a one-to-many from `MyLinkSection`.

It seems I have to declare the foreign key ID in `MyLink` which would seem to make this not possible.

Is there any way of setting up tables like this? With a normal DB I'd just have a field in `MyPage` called `my_link_id`, with something similar for `MyLinkSection`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is possible to specify forward relations:

```
PageUrl       MyLink `gorm:"ForeignKey:PageUrlId"`      
PageUrl Id    uint
```

Comment: This currently doesn't work: no FK is created by this declaration.